# why elassandra uninstall the elastic search default plugins?

Tags: elassandra

elastic search 6.2.3 comes with following plugins by default

GpsIUzc ingest-geoip       6.2.3
GpsIUzc ingest-user-agent  6.2.3
GpsIUzc x-pack-core        6.2.3
GpsIUzc x-pack-deprecation 6.2.3
GpsIUzc x-pack-graph       6.2.3
GpsIUzc x-pack-logstash    6.2.3
GpsIUzc x-pack-ml          6.2.3
GpsIUzc x-pack-monitoring  6.2.3
GpsIUzc x-pack-security    6.2.3
GpsIUzc x-pack-upgrade     6.2.3
GpsIUzc x-pack-watcher     6.2.3

but when I start elassandra not able to see none of the plugins, therefore my kibana won't start properly.

please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As answered on [this github issue](https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/issues/263) :

> Before elasticsearch 6.3, x-pack was not included in elasticsearch
>   code, see https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/open
>
> Elassandra currently rely on 6.2.3, so x-pack is not included, and
>   ingest plugin should be installed separately.

As of v6.2.3, x-pack is not officially supported by Elassandra developers and the official distribution won't succeed to install into elassandra because of a dependency issue (aka jarHell). The workaround is to remove the conflicting jars from the x-pack plugin zip before to install it.